# How to add My Python App to "Open with" in Windows

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Windows 10
I developed a Text Editor in PyQt5 and I want My Application also be added in "Open with"
for example:
if I right click a folder or file I can see "Open with Code" Because of Visual Studio Code
installed on my computer
Like that How can I add My own application to it using Python?

Thank you!

Comment: First you work out the correct command line to run your code. Then you add it like any other Open With application https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/add-opening-methods-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files-in-win/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid But I need to do it using Python code So?

Comment: So... the command line you need to run is something like `C:\pathtopython\python3.exe c:\pathtomyscript\myscript.py` First try that and ensure it works. Then you use the process I have linked to above to run that command line

Comment: To be clear, is it a requirement that you use python to add your application to the start menu? If so, you just need to find the correct pythin libraries that can be used to add things to the windows registry.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid But It is using Gui and I need to do it only with command line or any modules because my program automatically (if using command line I can use os.system()) should do it so what should I do for it?

Comment: Here is a python library that can change the windows registry. That's all that the GUI stuff is doing. You need to do what is shown in that link but you need to use a python librarry to do it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html